# Launching WCF only if not already running

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I have my WCF in my service References and when I run my WCF at the same time as I run my WPF using visual studio run multi projects then it all works fine, however I am now connecting multiple clients and if they start at the same time before no data is entered then it works. If one starts enters data then the other starts then the entered data is wiped. I have tried having it so it will start by running a host from my WPF. Unfortunately I get an error saying httpGetEnabled needs to be false, if this is false then I cannot update my service reference as it says there is an access issue. The code I have used for trying to run the host is.

```
try
{
    ServiceHost host;
    Service1.Service1Client service = new Service1.Service1Client();
    string baseAddress = "http://localhost:59849/Service1.svc";
    host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1.Service1Client));
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Service1.IService1),new BasicHttpBinding(), baseAddress);
    host.Open();          
    wcfHostId = wcf.generateId();
    textBox5.Text = "" + wcfHostId;
    button5.IsEnabled = false;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error = " + ex.Message);
}
```

Edit
So basically what I was saying is when I was self hosting a WPF and a new client connected it was wiping all the variables stored inside the service. And I was enquiring was it because of the way I was hosting the service?

Comment: See here: [Hosting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730158.aspx).

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow your question there, but you do have the WCFTestClient.exe located in your winsdk folder. This allows you to connect to your service and invoke methods. You may also enable WCF tracing on the serverside, and read the log it generates using the [Service Trace Viewer Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was the way I was trying to discover the WCF and didn't add a discovery endpoint.

```
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior());
host.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
```

needed to be added to the host part and the client code in the end was

```
var ep = "http://" + System.Net.Dns.GetHostName() + ":8732/DatabaseTransfer/Service1/";
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
binding.SendTimeout = new System.TimeSpan(0, 1, 30);
ChannelFactory<IService1> wcfFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(binding, new EndpointAddress(ep));
IService1 wcf = wcfFactory.CreateChannel();
```